# How to get Databricks workspace Spark job logs via APIs or message queue

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to create a service that looks for all the spark jobs' logs for a particular databricks workspace.
Lets say I have deployed two spark streaming jobs in a databricks workspace - I would like to get the logs of those two jobs via any API or via message queues like kafka/eventhubs.

That way, I can subscribe to those streaming logs and take some events based actions in real time.

Is there any APIs available in Databricks workspace - which will give us the logs of each spark jobs or can we get those spark application's custom logs over an event hub ?

Answer (score 0):

Databricks log delivery can be enabled at cluster level during cluster creation. If you have a dedicated cluster for your job (job cluster) then you can segregate based on the job. Not sure if an API is available for something like this, but cluster logs are delivered every 5 min or so : https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#cluster-log-delivery-1

Comment: question specifically about log delivery via API or message queue